# AWS Step functions Retry logic, maximum IntervalSeconds?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am working with AWS Step function steps, more specifically on the error handling.

In this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html, it mentions we can use the `Retry` clause if a step fails to retry the step:

```
"Retry": [ {
   "ErrorEquals": [ "States.Timeout" ],
   "IntervalSeconds": 3,
   "MaxAttempts": 2,
   "BackoffRate": 1.5
} ]
```

What is the maximum `IntervalSeconds` and `MaxAttempts` I can set? I want to be able to retry for a span for 2-4 days, retrying every 4 hours. Is it possible to set these fields at that high of a value? Example:

```
"Retry": [ {
   "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
   "IntervalSeconds": 14400,
   "MaxAttempts": 12,
   "BackoffRate": 1
} ]
```

Comment: Hi @RJK, a quick question Is this exponential retry or the incremental? Because, after this example, on the same page, under "Handling a failure using Retry" section, it says the backoff will be applied exponentially. Any idea? Did the above code work as your expectation which I believe is first attempt at 14400 sec, next attempt at 14401 sec, next attempt at 14402 sec etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum value for `IntervalSeconds` and `MaxAttempts` is `99999999`.
I don't see any mention of it in the documentation but you can verify by trying to create a sample state machine in the console or with API. i.e.

```
{
    "Comment": "A Retry example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda Function",
    "StartAt": "HelloWorld",
    "States": {
        "HelloWorld": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": ["CustomError"],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 99999999,
                    "MaxAttempts": 99999999,
                    "BackoffRate": 2.0
                },
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": ["States.TaskFailed"],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 99999999,
                    "MaxAttempts": 99999999,
                    "BackoffRate": 2.0
                },
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": ["States.ALL"],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 99999999,
                    "MaxAttempts": 99999999,
                    "BackoffRate": 2.0
                }
            ],
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```